# How to setup dual monitor?

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics

I have problems with configuring dual monitor on ubuntu 16.4.3 LTS on my notebook (MSI destroyer GX70 3CC). Currently when I connect external monitor, the built-in monitor turns off and I cannot see anything there although I can move mouse out of the screen just like the monitor is on.

One option I have tried is to set mirroring of displays with system settings. It doesn't seem to be permanent (at least I had to setup this again when I connected projector and after few days another monitor) and also it is quite irritating to move the settings window from turned-off built-in display to working one. This solution just made possible to operate the notebook but the built-in monitor stayed turned off.

Another option I have tried was writing my own xorg.conf file. I have tried to make it as general as possible so it can work with one or two monitors (any) depending on whether there is an external monitor connected. So far it doesn't work, I have ended up with this version but when I reboot ubuntu just freezes on login screen and after few seconds computer beeps and restart. This is possibly due to missing monitor which I unplugged to speed up the testing (when starting from recovery mode with failsafeX there are some errors with missing screen).

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "APU"
        Driver          "radeon"
        BusID           "PCI:0:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "GPU"
        Driver          "radeon"
        BusID           "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "VGA"
        Option          "Position" "1920 0"
        Option          "PrefferedMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "LVSD"
        Option          "Position" "0 0"
        Option          "Enable" "true"
        Option          "PrefferedMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Mon1"
        Monitor         "LVSD"
        Device          "APU"
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth 24
                Modes "1920x1080" #the resolutions of your monitors
                Virtual 3840 1080
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Mon2"
        Monitor         "VGA"
        Device          "GPU"
        SubSection "Display"
                Depth 24
                Modes "1920x1080" #the resolutions of your monitors
                Virtual 3840 1080
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier      "TwoMon"
        Screen       0  "Mon1"
        Screen       1  "Mon2" RightOf "Mon1"
EndSection
```

My questions are these. Why the built-in monitor doesn't work when external is connected? What is wrong with my current configuration? And is there any way to make general xorg.conf that will be able to operate one monitor when there are no external monitors connected and which will also be operatively able to extend display to another monitor when it connects?

At last, informations that might be helpful:

```
lspci | grep VGA
  00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
  01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Neptune XT [Radeon HD 8970M] (rev ff)
sudo lshw -c video # Only built-in monitor
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Richland [Radeon HD 8650G]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:36 memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff
```

Comment: Abandon custom `xorg.conf` - that way lies madness! Put things back the way they were (undo your changes), RightClick on the Gear in the top right, Select "System Settings", then Select "Screen Display".

Comment: I am totally aware that xorg.conf is the hard way but apparently I have no other choice because as I mentioned Settings-Display (display mirroring) haven't helped much. Of course I have tried to play with the settings but there was just no way to fix the problem.